# How to use callback from helper in codeigniter form validation?

Tags: codeigniter

My form validation code in controller is,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("name", "Name", "trim|callback_custom_validation");
if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {}
```

My helper code is,

```
function custom_validation($str) {
   // validation logic
}
```

If i move this `custom_validation` function to controller then it is working but it is not working as helper.
I need to call this function from controller and model so i am using helper.
So how to call from helper?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

You should create a helper file in the application/helpers folder and place the function in the helper file. Then load the helper file in your controller.

custom_validation.php:

```
function custom_validation($str) {
   // validation logic
}
```

Inside controller:

```
$this->load->helper('custom_validation');
```

You can also extend the Form_validation library.

Create a file: application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php

```
<?php
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
    public function custom_validation($str) {
       // validation logic
    }
}
```

And then just load it as normal validation:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|custom_validation');
```

Comment: I've done same thing as first method but helper is not called from form validation rules.

Comment: Second method is working fine with input validation but also i'm trying to validate input type file, so at that time it is not calling.

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom validation method to any model and use it in controllers and models like this example:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'name', 'Name',
            array(
                'trim',
                'required',
                array($this->Mymodel_m, 'custom_validation')
             )
 ); 

if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {...}
```

More info
**[Callable: Use anything as a rule](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callable-use-anything-as-a-rule)**